# Start SAS session with custom config (ole automation)

Tags: python, automation, sas, ole

I want to automate our information system with Python, because its interface (sas af) doesn't satisfy my needs. Local SAS8 system is used to connect to remote SAS to select data from DBs. As I understand this.

I used the SAS SCL language to add my extensions. But this language is a pain for me. Now I've found out that I can use Dispatch('SAS.Application') and Submit statements from Python. Ok. good.

But SAS system is called like

```
C:\SAS8\V8\sas.exe -autoexec autoexec.sas -config client.cfg
```

with C:\SAS8\VM-client as working directory. client.cfg sets main config

```
-config c:\sas8\v8\sasv8.cfg
```

and additional parameters. If I Dispatch('SAS.Application') it uses c:\sas8\v8\sasv8.cfg as config file and it doesn't find libraries in C:\SAS8\VM-client folder.

I want to start SAS session as usual, create session with remote sas as usual, and then submit sas statements from Python (make select call, download result to sas7bdat table, read it with sas7bdat python module).
It would be awesome to just set working directory and config file on dispatch, but it's impossible, isn't it?

Comment: Several days ago i tried to submit sas statements to sas command line automatically. It works but not very reliable, and that's very hacky.)

Comment: Are you trying to submit statements by placing them in interactive SAS via Python?  Or are you just running a batch program?  You can very easily create a SAS program file, submit it as a batch program, and in that batch session use a custom config.  I'm not sure if using Dispatch is the best way to go about things.

Comment: I want local SAS to be a "backend" of my Python application, so i can submit any statements i want. I don't need to execute one sas program and exit, but to execute different "rsubmit; proc sql ...; download ...;".